# Изменить картинку в input при нажатии Enter

Tags: jquery, html, css

Есть поле input. В CSS прописана картинка (галочка), которая находится слева от текста. Необходимо, чтобы ее с самого начала не было видно, а когда происходит нажатие на Enter, она показывалась.

[Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/jknkrtsr/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё решается через классы css, с помощью добавления нужного при событии:

```
$(function(){
    $("#adress_pokup").keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            $(this).addClass('true');
        }
    });
});
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/jknkrtsr/4/)

Comment: У вас серый фон пропадает, надо в .true продублировать background-color

Comment: @Darth, ну да, не заметил необязательных двух строк с бэкграундом, а можно ещё и транзишн запилить :) https://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/jknkrtsr/6/

Comment: Прям в точку, то, что надо!! Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

[Так](https://jsfiddle.net/jknkrtsr/5/)?